# r - Conditional Averaging using Aggregate with lists

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a script to simplify some data analysis, and at some point I need to take averages across some sublists that resemble:

```
> temp1[[1]]
      Replicate Week Treatment aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
C1_T0         1    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
C2_T0         2    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
C3_T0         3    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
C4_T0         4    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
H1_T0         1    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
H2_T0         2    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
H3_T0         3    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
H4_T0         4    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
```

To do this, I tried to use to aggregate function to take averages of all other columns as a function of the treatment columns, but this only succeeds for the first column, and then returns numbers that are definitely not the mean.

```
> temp10 <- aggregate( . ~ Treatment, temp1[[1]], mean)
> temp10
  Treatment Replicate Week aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1      Cold       2.5    1   1   1   1   1   1
2       Hot       2.5    1   1   1   1   1   1
```

It correctly returns the mean in the replicate column by treatment, but then I'm not quite sure why it's returning something different after that. I would guess that this data structure might be incompatible with the mean function, but then I'm not sure why the replicate mean is correct. Is there a better way to do this type of conditional averaging in lists, or would it be better to try to restructure everything as a dataframe?

Comment: it looks like all your columns are factors.  Check with `sapply(temp1[[1]], class)`.  You want to convert them to integers perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your columns are all `factors` and not `numeric`, you should always check the class of your `data.frame` columns before doing calculations like this, because, unfortunately, `aggregate` won't warn you that it took means of factors (which probably does not make sense at all).

To understand what is happening, look at what happens when you convert a factor in numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.factor(c(10, 10, 10, 10)))
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

So, reproducing your problem:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Replicate Week Treatment aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
C1_T0         1    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
C2_T0         2    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
C3_T0         3    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
C4_T0         4    0      Cold   1   2   3   4   5
H1_T0         1    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
H2_T0         2    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
H3_T0         3    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5
H4_T0         4    0       Hot   1   2   3   4   5", header = TRUE)

df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.factor)
temp10 <- aggregate( . ~ Treatment, df, mean)
temp10
  Treatment Replicate Week aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1      Cold       2.5    1   1   1   1   1   1
2       Hot       2.5    1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Notice that all means are ones because they were factors converted to numeric. In order to correct this you should transform your columns to numeric in a proper way (for example, using `as.numeric(as.character(x))`) or you should make sure to import your data properly. Doing that, `aggregate` will give you the answer you want:

```
columns <- c("Week", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee")
df[columns] <- lapply(df[columns], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
temp10 <- aggregate( . ~ Treatment, df, mean)
temp10
  Treatment Replicate Week aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1      Cold       2.5    0   1   2   3   4   5
2       Hot       2.5    0   1   2   3   4   5
```